# How to give ID to every input-form generated using v-for in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to generate number (passed as props) input forms and store the user inputs in the array inputValues.
My code looks as follows:

```
<template>
<div v-for="n in number" v-bind:key="n">
        <input ref= "inputs" v-bind:id="'str' + n" :v-model="inputValues[n]" />
        
      </div>
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'name',
  props: [
      'number',
    ],
  data() {
    return {
      inputValues: []
    }
  }
  });
```

But nothing gets stored in inputValues. What am I doing wrong? Also how can I give different ids to the input fields so I can style them differently in css later?

EDIT:  managed to get it to work!

```html
<div v-for="(n,i) in number"  v-bind:key="n">
        <input ref= "inputs" :id="'str' + n" v-model="inputValues[i]" />
        
</div>
```

Comment: When you manage to solve the issue, feel free to post an answer to your own question. It helps others who are looking for the same issue to find questions with valid and accepted answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work. v-bind: or ":" shouldn't be used on v-model. i added as index because n starts from 1 instead of 0.

```html
<div v-for="(n,i) in number"  v-bind:key="n">
        <input ref= "inputs" :id="'str' + n" v-model="inputValues[i]" />
        
</div>
```